# How to pass model to controller using JQuery AJAX?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jquery-ajax

I made AJAX that calls `IActionResult`. but I can't pass the model to it I just pass a string. My question is how to pass the model instead?

AJAX

```
    $('#CreateLesson').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        var lesson = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Lessons")',
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(lesson),
        success: function (data) { alert("succes"); },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
        });
    });
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody]string lesson)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(lesson);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return PartialView("_MyLessons", lesson);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("AjaxMetho", "Account");
        //return PartialView("Create");
    }
```

the text comes out is weird. it has fields more than the model. my model just has Name, grade, Objectives, Description.

> "Name=C%23%20vvvvvv&grade=1&SubID=123&BarCode=vvvvvvnnnnnnnnnnnnnn&Objectives=ABC%40abc123&Description=ABC%40abc123&__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8Ekvaq-NSQtAn7SGG0DJv7-ETDuOvAlwPoMzNMGyUSfJ6RRc2UY3KRxQbq0VEzBRE-YgHTSeMtnKY8DqTKXk8GoGsvkcB87xEM0-G5zbBO6BtoWLncH1ROE7iE2kiUbjBsPg_pwzZpXPUhS9_Nb14ay02l-N_DSULUT22cTa8zY5zpcyHY5Nsp-mN7tfLYiOGA"

when I try to pass the model without stringify and change the parameter of `IActionResult` to get Lesson Model instead of a string, I get null !!

what should I do to pass model proberly?

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier solution

```
// View
//<form id="CreateLesson" asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Lessons" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

// Ajax
$('#CreateLesson').on('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var lesson = $(this).serialize();
    var Url = $(this).attr('action');
    $.post(Url, lesson);

});

// Controller
//public JsonResult Create(Lesson lesson) { }
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you want to submit the data in the form via Ajax and then receive the model in the background. Here is a simple example(I passed data in formData,so controller don't need [FromBody]):

View:

```
 <form method="post" id="CreateLesson" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <h4>Name</h4>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="" />
        <h4>Grade</h4>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="grade" value="" />
        <h4>Objectives</h4>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="objectives" value="" />
        <h4>Description</h4>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </form>
```

Js in your view:

```
@section Scripts{
<script>
    $('#CreateLesson').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData($('#CreateLesson')[0]);
 
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Lessons/Create",
            async: true,
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Ok")
            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });
</script>}
```

Your Controller:

```
public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(Lesson lesson)
    {
       
        return RedirectToAction("AjaxMetho", "Account");
      
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I see it's working but it didn't work with me!! I found this easy solution => as posted. Thank you for your effort and time.